# Any way to substitute left join or it is necessary?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I would like to know if there is any better way to do the following query or if there is any necessity to make it better? (Considering that the DB load is not that big). The only criterion is that the 3 "variables" have to be included as AND, and the query can have more or less LEFT JOINS.

```
select `candidates`.* from `candidates` 
inner join `candidate_tag` on `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_tag`.`candidate_id` 
left join `tags` t1 on `t1`.`id` = `candidate_tag`.`tag_id` and t1.name like '%foo%'
left join `tags` t2 on `t2`.`id` = `candidate_tag`.`tag_id` and t2.name like '%baz%'
left join `tags` t3 on `t3`.`id` = `candidate_tag`.`tag_id` and t3.name like '%zoo%'
group by candidates.id
order by `candidates`.`last_name` asc
```

My first shot was the conditional query with `AND` operator but it didn't give me any results, so that is why I chose to change it to `left join` s.

Thanks!

Comment: Why the GROUP BY - when no aggregate functions involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find candidates who have one of three tags, you can also use conditional aggregation:

```
select c.*
from candidates c join
     candidate_tag ct
     on ct.candidate_id = c.id join
     tags t
     on ct.tag_id = t.id
where t.name like '%foo%' or
      t.name like '%baz%' or
      t.name like '%zoo%'
group by c.id
order by c.`last_name` asc;
```

You can also add `group_concat(t.name) as tags` to get the tags that candidates match.  Or, alternatively, if you only want candidates with all three, you can add a `having` clause:

```
having count(distinct t.name) = 3
```

or

```
having (max(t.name like '%foo%') +
        max(t.name like '%baz%') +
        max(t.name like '%zoo%')) = 3
```

You need this version if there are too "foo" tags, for instance.

Comment: I would need the `and` operator but in this case it doesn't work. Getting no results.

Comment: @Kornel . . . I fixed that.  I have no idea why I wrote it that way.  If you need all three in your original query, then you should use `inner join` there rather than `left join`.

Comment: wondering on the second `having` solution. The first is ok, it works, but now the second one doesn't. What if I have two or more 'foo' tags? How can be sure of the accuracy?

Comment: The first checks that there are three distinct tags for the candidate.  The second verifies that there is at least one "foo", "baz", and "zoo" tag.  So, foo1/foo2/foo3 would match the first `having`, but not the second.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
select `candidates`.id from `candidates` 
inner join `candidate_tag` on `candidates`.`id` = `candidate_tag`.`candidate_id` 
inner join `tags` t on `t`.`id` = `candidate_tag`.`tag_id`
group by candidates.id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN t.tag_name LIKE '%foo%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN t.tag_name LIKE '%bar%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1 AND SUM(CASE WHEN t.tag_name LIKE '%aaa%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 1
order by `candidates`.`last_name` asc
```

Comment: That couldn't give me a result in which t.name is 'foo' or t.name is 'baz' but not 'zoo'? I need the 3 included.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Explain yourself please.

Comment: I need the results with the three criteria included, with the `AND` operator. That doesn't give me any results. I already tried what you suggested as the solution. After that I chose to use left joins.

Comment: One candidate has one tag_id, and that only matches one tag... so how could ANYONE have the three of them at the same time?

Comment: I have a join table 'candidate_tag'

Comment: Ok now I get it, but you should explain the database structure in your OP. And you need to filter those who have the three tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80273/discussion-between-kornel-and-pinx0).